# Getting the data inside the C# web service from Jsonified string

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, json

In my JS I use Jquery's $ajax functions to call the web service and send the jsonified data to it. The data is in the following format:

```
var countries = {

   "1A": {
        id: "1A",
        name: "Andorra"        
    },
    "2B": {
        id: 2B
        name: "Belgium"       
    },

    ..etc
};

var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ data: data });
```

//then $ajax is called and it makes the call to the c# web service

---

On the c# side the web service needs to unpack this data, currently it comes in as string[][] data type. How do I convert it to the format so I can refer to the properties such as

.id and .name? Assuming I have a class called Sample with these properties?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my JS code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(countries);

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://localhost/MyService.asmx/Foo',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data: jsonData,
         success: function (msg) {                 
             alert(msg.d);
         },
         error: function (xhr, status) {
              switch (status) {
                 case 404:
                     alert('File not found');
                     break;
                 case 500:
                     alert('Server error');
                     break;
                 case 0:
                     alert('Request aborted');
                     break;
                 default:
                     alert('Unknown error ' + status);
             } 
         }
     });
```

inside c# web service I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string Foo(IDictionary<string, Country> countries)   
{

    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `string[][]` you are talking about and where does it come from but it is better to work with strong types. So define a custom type that will model your data:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then have the web method take a dictionary:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string Foo(IDictionary<string, Country> countries)
{
    // Here you will have countries["1A"].Name = "Andorra" and 
    // countries["2B"].Name = Belgi
    ...    
    return "success";
}
```

and then simply call this method (see `UPDATE` for proper data):

```
var data = {
   "1A": {
        id: "1A",
        name: "Andorra"        
    },
    "2B": {
        id: 2B
        name: "Belgi"       
    }
};
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myservice.asmx/Foo',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { JSON.stringify(data) },
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE:

Actually the request should be formatted like this:

```
var data = {
    countries: {
        "1A": {
            id: "1A",
            name: "Andorra"
        },
        "2B": {
            id: "2B",
            name: "Belgium"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks:) but I am also sending other data to this web service. Currently, my web service looks like  [WebMethod]

        public void Foo(string[][] data)
        {
           //do whatever
        }
Inside the data parameter, data[0] contains credentials, data[1] contains the actual array of the objects....

Comment: @gnomixa, what other data? Everything could be represented with strong types. So define a base object that contains as a property this dictionary and as another property your other data you are passing. Just get rid of this `string[][]`. It makes your web method unmaintainable.

Comment: Of course, you just need to model your data with strong types.

Comment: ok I will re-phrase. If I am sending two different types of variables to the web service. Foo(IDictionary<string, Country> countries)
will not work, since it only unpacks ONE type - Country....am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: @gnomixa, you won't be sending two different types. You will send a single type containing two properties: `Foo(MyModel model)` where MyModel contains the Countries dictionary and some other property holding your other data.

Comment: so what type would MyModel be? A custom defined one?

Comment: gives me unknown error upon come back. Are there any attributes I need to set to use IDictionary?

Comment: by the way: this line data: { JSON.stringify(data) } gives me a JS error.

Comment: @gnomixa, also make sure that your web service class has been decorated with the `[ScriptService]` attribute.

Comment: thanks! one last question, why this:     var countries = {
           "1A": {
                id: "1A",
                name: "Andorra"        
            },
            "2B": {
                id: "2B",
                name: "Belgi"       
            }
    };


    data["countries"] = countries; doesn't work? Is the only way to pack the array by defining it? there is no way to assign variables as above?

Comment: @gnomixa, the web service method parameter is called `countries`, so the same property should be present in the serialized JSON request.

Comment: I understand....but wouldn't data.countries = countries; do exactly that? I mean, in coding, you don't always define the structure statically. Sometime, I need to populate it dynamically. for some reason if I do data.countries = countries it won't work.

Comment: @gnomixa, where are you using this code? Client or server? I am not sure I understand you.

Comment: got it. I had to declare data like this: var data = new Object;

Comment: on the client. I would like to compose the data to sent to the .net web service. Declaring it statically is not always possible so I had to be able to assign its properties. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: something just occured to me - don't we lose flexibility by defining MyModel? What if I want to pass multiple different arrays? all of different objects? Do I need to define a List of IDictionary in MyModel class to support that?

Comment: @gnomixa, indeed if everything is dynamic in your scenario defining static types might not be the best solution.

Comment: hence  I was using string[][] - it may not be as manageable, but it is very flexible. I can pretty much send whatever i want. Is there a way to convert string[][] to Country object without using the dictionary? which is what the original question was about. I would rather not define 10 static types for each web service method.

Comment: @gnomixa, no there isn't an easy way to do this. It's just a dynamic double dimension string array which is not strongly typed.

Comment: I opened another question regarding this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718656/sending-data-to-c-web-service-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: aha, got it:) I simply will pass several parameters, and unpack them instead of passing one parameter of MyModel custom type.

Comment: Darin, see this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939829/can-not-serialize-interface-message-for-web-service; I am stumped. If you could help, that would be great. It looks like I need to do a little extra if I want to pass IDictionary object inside my web service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)?  As you said, assuming you have a class with these properties, it should/might be able to [deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx) the JSON string to that type.