# Sending data to C# web service from Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, json

Suppose I have a web service/web method called service.asmx/Test. I have several methods in this web service.

I wish to send some data to any given method. The data is composed of several things, and each method can have different types of variables sent to it. Currently, i use string[][] type so my web service looks like this:

```
 [WebMethod]

        public void Test(string[][] data)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
```

it has been mentioned to me that it is not the best way to do it. A lot of people use IDictionary and define strong types...but it seems that it would add more complexity. What is the correct way to do it? What type of variable should I use, List, string[][], myCustomType?

If I do use MyCustom type, I would like to make it more generic such as

```
public class MyCustom {

        public string user { get; set; }
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string client { get; set; }
        public string server { get; set; }

        Array<Object> params;

}
```

where data is an array of objects, each may be of a different type.

So the method would now look like:

```
[WebMethod]

        public void Test(MyCustom data)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Decided to pass several parameters instead of passing ONE parameter of MyCustom type.This solves both maintainability and flexibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can use JSON to post data to your web service. Also in you web Service, you have to add this:
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
Then what you can do is, you use json object as data of your ajax call and asp.net will take care of the rest.